# Keydown on dynamic added table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to create Jquery function to detect keydown in dynamic added table,
but it wont work :
this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#create').on('click',function(){
      $('#test').append(<table class='dynamic'><tr><td><div class="focus">Name</div></td></tr><tr><td>address</td></tr>)
     });
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if($(e.target).closest('table').hasClass('dynamic')&& $(e.target).hasClass('focus'))
        {
          alert('ok');
        };
    })
 });
```

and this is my html :

```
<BODY>
  <DIV ID="test"></DIV>
<button id="create">create it!</button>
</BODY>
```

please help me gusy

Answer (score 0):

I found several errors in your sample. First, is that without input fields any keydown event will be fired on document element and you never will get your condition true. Second, is a code issue. You can't use jQuery functions without wrapping DOM elements into jQuery object.  `if(e.target.closest('table').hasClass('dynamic')`

As example I made a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/qnvfru26/1/) for you. Also I guess you may be interested in such implementation but using [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/#mouseover-handler) event, which would be better for your case

Comment: thaks sir for your answer, but i need firing an alert only if keydown inside the table td

Comment: This event will never be fired out inside the table, because your table does not contain any input field. Keydown event will reference always to root element. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown). So in this case you will be able to achieve your requirment only by adding at least one input field.